# Increment operator java

Tags: java

The first index++ displays the value of "1" instead of "2".

Why doesn't the value gets incremented?

Any inputs would be helpful.

```
    package scratch;

    class Feline {
        {
            index = 1;
        }
            int index;
          public static void main(String[] args) {
              new Feline().go();
          }

         void go(){
             System.out.println(index);
             System.out.println(index++);
             System.out.println(index++);
             System.out.println(index++);
         }
        }

Result:
1
1
2
3
```

Comment: Because it prints, *then* increments. `++index` will increment, *then* print. Postfix versus prefix.

Comment: Did you even tried searching for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're using the post-increment operator `++` that occurs after the variable to increment.  Its value is the current value of the variable, and the increment happens afterwards.

[JLS 15.14.2 covers this:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)

> [T]he value 1 is added to the value of the variable and the sum is
>   stored back into the variable.

and

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the
>   variable before the new value is stored.

It does get incremented -- after the current value is returned.

```
System.out.println(index);
```

... just prints `1`.

```
System.out.println(index++);
```

... prints `1` *then* increments `index` to `2`.

```
System.out.println(index++);
```

... prints `2` *then* increments `index` to `3`.

```
System.out.println(index++);
```

... prints `3` *then* increments `index` to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

That is what Post Increment do.

```
         System.out.println(index);
         System.out.println(index++);//printed index and  +1 to the index
         System.out.println(index++);
         System.out.println(index++);
```